# How to set up custom fields in Superset?

Tags: sql, reporting, business-intelligence, apache-superset

Our database has a field with JSON data that we'd like to use in reports. E.g.

```
{
  owner_type: "USER",
  updated_at: 1641996749092389600,
  version_no: 1,
  entity_type: "INDIVIDUAL",
  country:"ES",
}
```

How can one create dynamic fields in Superset, e.g. to expose `owner_type` as its own field?

I'm coming from tools like Snowflake and Zoho Analytics where you could build Views, Dynamic Tables and Formula Fields based on aggregated raw data.

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns to your table in Superset. Hover on 'Sources' on the header and select 'Tables'. Then from there, choose the option to edit the record of your table. In that you can add a calculated column/custom column.
To add a column for `owner_type`, lets name the custom column as `owner_type`. Fill the datatype for the new column as `VARCHAR(100)`. Choose the table from the dropdown. In the expression, put `json_column->"$.owner_type"` and then hit save. This expression is for MySQL database. You can find the expression to parse JSON in your particular DB.